# Yum install not recognizing specific version of JDK package on Oracle Linux 7.9

Tags: linux, yum, oracle-linux, jdk

I am trying to install jdk 1.8.0_311 using yum install. However, I am getting an error stating that there is "nothing to do" when attempting to install.

I have used

```
yum --showduplicates list jdk*
```

to check that the package is there

```
jdk-20-headful.aarch64             2000:20.0.1-9.el7                ol7_oci_included
jdk-20-headless.aarch64            2000:20-36.el7                   ol7_oci_included
jdk-20-headless.aarch64            2000:20.0.1-9.el7                ol7_oci_included
jdk1.8.aarch64                     2000:1.8.0_301-fcs               ol7_oci_included
jdk1.8.aarch64                     2000:1.8.0_311-fcs               ol7_oci_included
jdk1.8.aarch64                     2000:1.8.0_331-fcs               ol7_oci_included
jdk1.8.aarch64                     2000:1.8.0_341-fcs               ol7_oci_included
jdk1.8.aarch64                     2000:1.8.0_351-fcs               ol7_oci_included
```

I then attempted to run

`yum install jdk1.8.aarch64-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs`

and I get the error "Nothing to do"

```
yum install jdk1.8.aarch64-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package jdk1.8.aarch64-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

According to the documentation, this is the correct way to install this, but it is not recognizing the package. If i do not specify the version, it defaults to a newer version (351) that I cant use.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it already installed? `rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}\n' | grep jdk` Does this works? `yum install jdk1.8.aarch64-2000`

Comment: It does not appear to be installed. I attempted to run `yum install jdk1.8.aarch64-2000` and received the same error as in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to install a particular version of a package is:

`yum install <package_name>-<version>`

That <package_name> should not include the architecture name (.aarch64 in your case).

Try running:

`yum install jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs`

if you would like to specify the architecture, then run something like this:

`yum install jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs.aarch64`

Comment: I tried this and got these result

`sudo yum install jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Same error as before

Comment: I realized I mistyped the lower command, after fixing my typo, it worked. I had to specify the architecture, as if I did not, it was unable to find the package. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yum reacts not really consistent regarding "yum install", "yum erase" and "yum list installed":
For installation you can use "abbreviated" pkg names "pkgname-pkgversion" like:

```
yum install jdk1.8-1.8.0_311-fcs
```

For "yum list installed" and "yum erase" you must use "full package name" (like mentioned in previous solution) or use globs (no regex) like:

```
> yum list installed jdk*
Installed Packages
jdk1.8.x86_64                              2000:1.8.0_311-fcs
> yum erase jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs*
> yum erase jdk1.8-*1.8.0_311-fcs*
/* That's similar to abbreviated installation syntax ("pkgname-*pkgversion*"), avoiding "2000" + <architecture> */
```

"architecture" is listed in output of "yum list installed ..." as part of the package name (see above: "jdk1.8.**x86_64**"), but in "real world" (for **usage** of "yum erase" and "yum list installed") it's located AFTER the version in "full package name":

```
jdk1.8-2000:1.8.0_311-fcs.x86_64
```

No idea, why it's implemented like this or why you can leave out "2000" with "yum install" ...